# Creating an android fragment that opens another fragment based on button activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm trying to create an activity that adds a dynamic fragment at runtime. From that  fragment I want to be able to open six other fragments on button click. [Going to use a case to implement this most likely]

Think of it as a windows 8 UI; with 6 buttons, each one opens a new fragment.

Unfortunately I have no idea how to go about this. I can't seem to get the button to pass data back to the main activity. I've also lost quite a bit of my code due to a git mishap. Here's what I recreated.

If you have any tips on coding style, syntax, java, OO- those are all welcome too. I'm coming from a C background. My end goal would be to create a replaceFragment(Frag) method for some easy syntactic sugar later on. Though I couldn't implement that with any success so far.

Another small question with fragments - I'm trying to add them dynamically at run-time - do I need to create all of them at run time? So each one needs a .add [Drink fragment, Menu fragment] or do I just need to do the .replace

## SingleFragmentActivity.java

```
 public abstract class SingleFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity{
protected abstract Fragment createFragment();

FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE); //Lock screen orientation for app

    Fragment frag = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
    fm.beginTransaction()
    .add(R.id.fragment_container,frag)
    .commit();
}
```

}

## Customer_Activity.java

```
public class Customer_Activity extends SingleFragmentActivity {
    
    public static Context appContext;

            @Override
            protected Fragment createFragment() {
                return new CustomerSelectionFragment();
            }
}
```

## CustomerSelectionFragment

```
public class CustomerSelectionFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener{



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customer_selection_fragment, container, false);
    //Buttons should be placed here?
    Button btnDrink = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.Drink);
    btnDrink.setOnClickListener(this);
    
    Button btnMenu = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.Menu);
    btnDrink.setOnClickListener(this);

    return v;
}

//implement the onClick method here
public void onClick(View v) {
   // Perform action on click
  switch(v.getId()) {
    case R.id.Drink:
     //Not sure how to pass "Create Drink Fragment to activity?
      break;
    case R.id.Menu:
      //Pass Create Menu fragment to activity?
      break;
      }
   }
    

    
    
  }
```

Totally ok with people editing my post for good-faith reasons [clarity, etc].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any communication between fragments should be done via activity . Here is the link to developers site http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html , the tutorial is about communicating between fragments and pretty much explains everything.